# wget recursive how to format a string for download

Tags: linux, wget

hi i want create a wget string for download recursive all structure of this link
`https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/daily/klines/`  and  put it  in my directory DataCollection but i dont know  why not  work  anyone  can help me ?? thanks
this is my string
`wget -r -A zip  -nc -x -P /home/stefano/Documenti/ring/applications/1_MYPROG/BINANCE-DATA-COLLECTION-DW/DataCollection  https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/daily/klines/`

Answer (score 0):

> dont know why not work

I did downloaded `https://data.binance.vision/?prefix=data/spot/daily/klines/` using `wget` and there are not links like `1INCHBTC`, `1INCHBUSD`, `1INCHDOWNUSDT` which you can see in browser. They are apparently provided by JavaScript and GNU `wget` does not support JavaScript execution so there are not links for `wget` to follow. If you want to scrape this site you would need tool which do support JavaScript.